# Como impedir a visualização de um elemento no Microsoft Edge e no Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge

o navegador da microsoft quebra o meu site, isso pq ele é laravel/bootstrap, imagine se não fosse, não tenho nada contra a microsoft, preciso apenas cobrir o site de preto e exibir a mensagem não suportado, isso me da tempo para arrumar ou fazer uma versão só para este navegador

tentei isso, mais não dá em nada

```
<!--[if IE]>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Voce está rodando essa pagina no Internet Explorer');
    </script>

<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
if(isIE == true){
    var ie = '<style>body{background-color:black:!important; .did{color:white:!important;} </style><div><center><h1 class="did"> nao suportado</h1><center></div>';
}else{
     var ie = '';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atribua um ID ao body ou a uma `div` mestra que comporte todo conteúdo válido, depois você cria um .css e chama ele no cabeçalho da página do jeito que você fez. Depois você cria uma `div` com a mensagem e fundo que você quer que seja exibido, porém, com padrão escondido usando `display: none;`.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="meudeemergencia.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Dentro do css, você mostra a div da mensagem e esconde a que você desejar:

```
// CSS para IE

#corpoSite{
    display: none ! important;
}

#divComMensagemErro{
    display: block ! important;
    width: 100vw ! important;
    height: 100vh ! important;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

```
<div id="divComMensagemErro"> <!-- Esta div mostra o erro -->
 <p>Navegador não suportado</p>
</div>

<div id="corpoSite"> <!-- Esta div comporta toda página -->
 <p>Navegador suportado, site rodando belezinha</p>
</div>
```